# cython ctypedef syntax: quoted string at end?

Tags: cython

I am working at understanding the `petsc4py` sources. In them one finds many `ctypedef` declarations of the following form:

```
ctypedef <type> <typename> "<C typename>"
```

for instance the following:

```
ctypedef char* PetscMatType "const char*"
```

or

```
ctypedef struct PetscMatStencil "MatStencil":
    PetscInt k,j,i,c
```

(In this second case `MatStencil` is a type that will be known to C at compile time because of its definition in a PETSc header file.)

I have not been able to find any explanation in the Cython documentation that explains this use of a quoted string in a `ctypedef` statement. (I gather from context that it is a hint to `cythonize` to implement the Cython type being defined with the named C type.)  Can anyone tell me where to find this documented?

More generally, is there anywhere a comprehensive Cython reference? The main documentation I know of is that at [`cython.readthedocs.io`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This is helpful, but it is not a comprehensive reference. For instance, if you search it for `ctypedef`, you find a bunch of examples, but none of the syntax I asked about above. What you do not find there is a comprehensive definition of `ctypedef` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a document that's a more comprehensive reference than the documentation you linked. It actually does have what you're asking about in it, although I suspect you need to know what you're looking for to find it (unfortunately): https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications:

> For special cases where namespacing or renaming on import is not enough, e.g. when a name in C conflicts with a Python keyword, you can use a C name specification to give different Cython and C names to the C function at declaration time. Suppose, for example, that you want to wrap an external C function called yield(). If you declare it as:
>
> ````
> cdef extern from "myheader.h":
>     void c_yield "yield" (float speed)```
> ````

It then goes on to show other examples of structs and variables being renamed (but not specifically typedefs).

Essentially the assumption is that usually when you wrap something in Cython you want to use the same name in Cython as you do in C. However sometimes that doesn't work and this "quoted string" syntax lets you specify a different name that matches your C code.

It's a useful trick to know about because it often lets you work round Cython limitations - for example when wrapping a single variant of a heavily templated C++ class without exposing the whole template hierarchy. In these cases I suspect that the `const` in `const char` was confusing Cython, and that the author wanted to use `MatStencil` as the name in the Python interface (so needed a different name for the C interface). Lying to Cython about small details is often helpful...